# JDBC dependency for Maven on Spring mvc

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I am using oracle DB to connect with my java code on below used platform:

- STS- 3.8.2
- Spring -2.0.0.0 release
- Maven
- Oracle database XE version.

While running the spring boot app,I am getting error of jdbc driver not found for database connection string.

I tried to resolve the same by adding all related dependency, however none of them showing me valid, and also it is unable to download required jar during maven build.

I have also tried manually placing the jars in ./m2 directory by downloading from open source, but still not working.

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: 1. Oracle jdbc is no open source 2. show us your pom and the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the maven dependency of Oracle-connector. Oracle connector is 
   missing so it is giving this error.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
  <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, However as I have mentioned ,
 tried various version of ojdbc jars and dependencies like above. But for each case, my STS is unable to download related ojdbc jar into my program. However as a workaround I have placed the jar manualluy to another file location and mentioned below parameter to identify it in pom.xml <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>

However still looking for solution to this problem, not sure whether it is a global issue or specific to my application .

Comment: So delete all the jars in .m2 folder and update your maven project again.